# ListView shows some numbers instead of fields of object

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android and practising some basic stuff. I made my first android application, and in src folder in package I made class `Products` in same package with class MainActivity. 
In MainActivity I create `ListView` with simple_list_item_1.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.bill);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Products>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tn);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and made button

```
    Button drink=(Button)findViewById(R.id.coffe);
    drink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Products c=new Products("coffe","100,00");          
            adapter.add(c);
        }

});
```

When I run it on my tablet, application works, but when I press button `drink` instead of showing me `coffe 100,00` on list, it shows  `com.ana.helloworld.Products@410c9a40`

Class Products is basic

```
   package com.ana.helloworld;

   public class Products {

private String name = "noname";
private String price="null";

public Products(){
    };

public Products(String name,String price)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
};

public String getPrice(){
return price;}

public void setPrice(String p){
    price=p;}

public String getName(){
    return name;}

public void setName(String n){
    name=n;}

     }
```

Maybe class Products should be in some other package? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is `tn` can u plz show more code where you are adding value inn `tn` ?

Comment: in which activity is your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a toString method for your Product class, something like this would do:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append(name);
    str.append("\n");
    str.append(price);

    return str.toString(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a toString()-method that displays what you want instead of the default one provided by Object, which does the Classname@123f12 stuff.